# Setting up the same repository twice under different names in janky

Tags: git, cucumber, hubot, janky

I have a build server which leverages janky as the glue between jenkins and hubot.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a clean way in janky to duplicate a specific repository under a different name?

The main problem that I'm trying to solve is that I have a regular build job and I would like to create a separate job that runs the complete test suite only when certain conditions occur. All that while I still leverage the benefits of janky (web interface, hubot controls, etc.).

As far as I could tell there was no clean way to create a second job in janky that points to the exact same github repository. Looking at the application, I wonder if I should  try to hack in an interface through janky's console. Has anyone had the same issue as me? If so, how did they solve this problem? I would like to keep janky in the picture, if feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is extremely simple to do.

When setting up a repository in janky, you use the command

```
ci setup github/janky
```

Where github is the username, and janky is the repository.

You can add both a nickname, and a template to use for this

```
ci setup github/janky janky-full full
```

the `janky-full` will be how you refer to the repository - so - if you wanted to do a full build - you'd call

```
ci build janky-full
```

The `full` represents the `xml.erb` file in your `config/` dir (which contains default.xml.erb and environment.rb by default)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Under the hood I was receiving another error which gave me the false impression that this wasn't possible.